# how to add property in c# object without modify core object c# 4.0

Tags: c#, object, lazy-loading

I have a object `User` that is used in a core project.

```
public struct User
{
    public int Id;
    // Few details here.
}
```

I have a another project in which I have same `User` object. What I want is to use the `User` from the core project. Now I found that the `User` in the core project has some properties that my project does not have. I have everything ready in both projects.

Now I change all the code as `MyCoreProject.ProjectClass.User`. Now, I think properties like those which are part of my project will create an Exception like 'User.PropertyofmyOwnproject is not part and no extension method found'.

Now I want to know how I need to inherit the `User` from core. I can't change any code in Core project. What I can do is modify only my own code so I access properties of both `User` classes. Both versions of `User` have to access a database.

How do I need to inherit my `User` from the core project?

If their is a option to make something like Lazy object which load properties only when it's called then how it will work?

What is the practical approach to solve this issue?

Comment: Wouldn't inheriting from `User` be an option in your case?

Comment: Can you please show me some code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an additional class in your project, which inherits from User, and which implements the properties and methods your other project cannot use.